# Display Parent Page Title Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

Im really new with Orchard CMS. I need help in how to display the parent page title in a part of a page (marked in the screenshot here: https://www.diigo.com/item/image/2v4y4/2y3m).

I am stuck for several days already and its really hard to find a solution in google. :(

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're saying you want the page title in another zone in your layout.  You can do this easily in your placement.info file...

```
<Place Parts_Title="/Header:1" />
```

Assuming of course that your zone is named "Header".  To restrict this to the "Page" content type you could add a match...

```
<Match ContentType="Page">
  <Place Parts_Title="/Header:1" />
</Match>
```

Comment: Wow it works! I used my custom part name to make it unique. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Now, how about adding custom css class for each page? Like page-name class in the body tag?

Comment: Cool. The css thing probably deserves a whole separate question.